# Route to different sets of views without creating models and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a simple web app and will have two types of users: admin and user. I do not want to create separate models and controllers for them. To access their own views of home page, I have this (ex. for admin)

```
<%= link_to 'Add Book', new_book_path %> 
<%= link_to 'Search book', new_admin_search_path %>
```

I want to have a different view of search results for them. For example, I want the admin to be able to edit the book and the user able to view the comments. But how do I route the path? The search page can be the same, but the result pages will be different. I have tried to add `scope` to routes.rb but whichever user type that was wrote first gets the path header.

In other words, with new.html.erb, how do I route to different show.html.erb. I have a model and controller for search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render` to render different show view https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

First you create 2 views for admin and user in app/views/users.

Then, in your users controller:

```
def show
  if user.type === 'admin'
    render 'admin_show' # if user is admin, use view admin_show.html.erb
  else
    render 'user_show' # use view user_show.html.erb
  end
end
```